# CSS Styling ignored on page load

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

In the process of creating my first Rails 4 app but something strange is happening...

Everytime I click on a link to go to another page within the app the css is ignored. Then if I refresh the page the styling appears again! Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Comment: Please post your relevant code so we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: no code would be helpful here - my question isn't about how to use css - it appears more to be a bug or local server issue

Comment: It could be a syntax issue, it would be helpful to see how you are linking the CSS in your head, perhaps the folder structure of where you are storing your CSS file.

Comment: well what might be of more use is better description of the issue - I have noticed that if I type the url directly into the browser address bar there is no issue but if I use a link then the styling is ignored until i refresh the page.

Comment: Is that NO styling is applied (i.e. stylesheet isn't loading), or your updates aren't immediately registering? If the latter is the case, it'd be aggressive caching on Rails part.

Comment: NO styling is applied but if I view source there is a reference to the correct style sheet

Comment: What browser(s) are you testing with?